# tkinter (py3) - change image labels, inside functions, in real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning to use tkinter, and what I've tried to do is have 4 buttons on a coffee machine, and each button would create a new window, which would show images in order, like a slideshow. What I've done doesn't work, as it only shows the last image in the slideshow, and ignores the rest. In python 2.7, I was able to fix it by printing nothing into the console after every configuration of the label, but it doesn't seem to work. If you could tell me why this happens, and/or how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.

(P.S. I know that my code is probably very ugly/inefficient, but bear in mind that I'm very new to tkinter, so I only really care that it works).

```
def Latte():
    global Grind
    global Hot_Water
    global Cocoa_Poweder
    global Steamed_Milk
    global Foamed_Milk
    global LattePhoto

    MakingCoffee=Toplevel(Test, width=200, height=200)
    MakingCoffee.wm_title("Latte")
    MakingCoffee.iconbitmap("Photos\Latte.ico")

    photolabel= Label(MakingCoffee,image=Grind)
    photolabel.pack()
    time.sleep(2)
    photolabel.configure(image=Hot_Water)
    time.sleep(2)
    photolabel.configure(image=Steamed_Milk)
    time.sleep(4)
    photolabel.configure(image=Foamed_Milk)
    time.sleep(1)
    photolabel.configure(image=LattePhoto)
    time.sleep(2)
    MakingCoffee.destroy()
```

Comment: It would be best if you post the most crucial and related parts of the code here, instead of linking to an outside resource.

Comment: The most crucial parts of the code are those in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small sample of one way to make this work. You can restructure as needed. The list is just so I can iterate through it showing the changes. You don't need all of those globals in your original code. They're already global variables and you're not attempting to reassign them so this a redundancy. You can factor out ~50% of your code at least to be reusable. You can make this a class and make a "factory class" to create different types of slideshows with different types of coffee, and then you could also get rid of the `global` here as well.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import time

Test = tkinter.Tk()
Test.wm_title("Coffee Store")
Test.resizable(0, 0)

americano_images = [
    PhotoImage(file='1.gif'), 
    PhotoImage(file='2.gif'), 
    PhotoImage(file='3.gif')
]
AFTER = None

AmericanoPhoto= PhotoImage(file="1.gif")

def switch_images(im_list, label, index=0):

    global AFTER
    label.configure(image=im_list[index])
    if index != len(im_list) - 1:
        index += 1
    else:
        index = 0
    AFTER = Test.after(1000, lambda: switch_images(im_list, label, index))

def Americano():

    MakingCoffee=Toplevel(Test, width=200, height=200)
    MakingCoffee.wm_title("Americano")

    photolabel= Label(MakingCoffee)
    photolabel.pack_propagate(0)
    photolabel.pack()
    after = switch_images(americano_images, photolabel)
    cancel = Button(MakingCoffee, text='Kill Slideshow', 
        command=lambda: Test.after_cancel(AFTER))
    cancel.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

B1= Button(Test, text='BUTTON', command=Americano)
B1.grid(row=0,column=0)

Test.mainloop()
```