# My program uses a lot of ram memory, what can I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ram

My program is using a lot of ram memory, what it does is this:

1. Downloads an image from an online camera.
2. Shows the image in the window (Tkinter window)
3. Deletes the image.
4. The same process again (infinite loop untill the window is closed)

This is the code:

```
def show_image(self, cam):
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        self.update_image(cam)

        load = Image.open(cam.getPlace() + "/image.jpeg")
        load.thumbnail((400, 300))
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        if cam.getPlace() == "FrontYard1":
            try:
                img1 = Label(image=render)
                img1.image = render
                img1.grid(row=0, column=0)
            except:
                print("Error")
        elif cam.getPlace() == "FrontYard2":
            try:
                img2 = Label(image=render)
                img2.image = render
                img2.grid(row=0, column=1)
            except:
                print("Error")
        elif cam.getPlace() == "Garden1":
            try:
                img3 = Label(image=render)
                img3.image = render
                img3.grid(row=1, column=0)
            except:
                print("Error")
        else:
            try:
                img4 = Label(image=render)
                img4.image = render
                img4.grid(row=1, column=1)
            except:
                print("Error")

        print("And " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " to run show image")

def update_image(self, cam):
    os.remove(cam.getPlace()+"/image.jpeg")
    if cam.getModel() == "Model":
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(#link and folder to download the image)
    else:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(#link and folder to download the image)
```

I tried using gc.collect() but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Infinite loop will obviously use a lot of ram

Comment: I have recently ran into this issue my self. In short, I perform data processing on images. At then end of each processing (at the end of a loop) I figured that most of the memory should be released since I call the destructor. However, not the case and I had memory build up. My solution was to build a wrapper that calls the processing script individually for each image. Thus, when the processing is done the python process is terminated and the memory released. If you want a more detailed answer I would be happy to write it up.

Comment: Re-use the labels (create 4 on application start, then re-use them). Maybe that could help. (`img[1-4].configure(image=render)`)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603223/tkinter-py3-change-image-labels-inside-functions-in-real-time

Comment: Do you have an actual symptom here, like memory errors or the computer going into swap hell or something, or are you just worried by scary numbers in Activity Monitor/Task Manager/whatever? Because often the only problem is people taking those numbers to mean a problem when they don’t.

Comment: @abarnert The program crashes when it reaches 1.8gb of ram approximately.

Comment: Anyway, this code has a serious problem independent of memory: you have a `while True:` that never returns to the tkinter event loop, so you’re not responding to events. What you almost certainly want is a function that just does this one time, and then does something like `self.root.after(0, self.show_image, cam)`.

Comment: @KyleSwanson Would you please?

Comment: @abarnert I am using multithreading, so that tkinter can respond.

Comment: @SantiagoPardal You can't create `Label`s, or access any tkinter widgets, from a background thread, unless you're using something like `mtTkinter` to wrap those calls up so they're really just posting a job on a queue that the `mtTkinter` main thread services so it can run the job on the main thread.

Comment: @SantiagoPardal no problem! Busy at the moment, but later today i can.

Comment: @KyleSwanson Doing the processing in a subprocess so it can release the memory can be helpful, but I don't think it's at all relevant to the OP's problem here. That would be the solution if the problem were, e.g., that one image occasionally took a huge amount of memory and you needed to release it to the OS as soon as possible. But the problem here is that the `Label` instances live forever, and therefore the final processed images do; the intermediate storage used in processing is a red herring.

Comment: You could perhaps ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is attempting to create an infinite number of `Label` objects, hiding each one behind an infinite stack of other labels. This obviously leads to problems unless you have infinite memory.

What you *want* is just four labels at any given time. You need to keep track of the labels you’ve created and ideally just reuse them, or, if not, destroy them instead of just hiding them behind new ones.

---

Currently, your code is keeping track of the labels in those `img1` through `img4` variables, except that they don’t get created until the first time they show an image, so you can’t check them. So, before the loop, you’ll either want to create four empty labels, or just set the variables to `None`. Then, inside the loop, you can do this (assuming you went with`None` instead of empty labels):

```
    if cam.getPlace() == "FrontYard1":
        try:
            if img1 is None:
                img1 = Label(image=render)
                img1.grid(row=0, column=0)
            else:
                img1.image = render
        # etc.
```

---

You could simplify this by storing the labels in a dict instead of four separate variables:

```
imgs = {“Front Yard 1": img1, …}
```

… and then replacing the if/elif chain with a dict lookup:

```
img = imgs.get(cam.getPlace())
```

Although here, you’re almost certainly going to want to go with empty labels instead of `None` for the initial values.

---

As a side note, your program has another very serious problem. A `while True:` loop obviously never returns to the tkinter event loop. This means you don’t give tkinter a chance to update the display, or respond to mouse events or quits or other events from the window system, so your app is going to be nonresponsive and pop up a beach ball or hourglass or whatever.

To fix this, you need to remove the loop and instead have your method just retrieve and process one image and then call `after` to ask tkinter to call it again the next time through the event loop.

This will also require changing those local `img1` variables (or the dict `imgs` suggested above) into instance variables.

If you were trying to use a background thread for this task, it's illegal to do anything to tkinter widgets from any thread but the main thread. On some platforms, this will just give you an immediate error, or hang the GUI. On other platforms, it will seem to work, but every once in a while do something weird—which is even worse.

If you're working around this via, e.g., a Python 3 fork on `mtTkinter` (which wraps the `Queue` logic shown in [the Effbot Book](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm), so everything you do on a widget actually posts a message for the main thread to process), then you can ignore this section. But if not, you want to either do that, or do the same thing manually (as shown in the linked page), or just get rid of the background thread and use `after`.

---

While we're at it, a bare `except:` that just prints `Error` is hiding any problems that might show up and making it harder to debug things, so you should almost never do that.

Also, is the `Label.image` assignment really the only place that can raise here?

---

Putting it all together:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.imgs = {}
    img1 = Label()
    img1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.imgs["Frontyard1"] = img1
    # ... likewise for 2-4

def show_image(self, cam):
    start_time = time.time()

    try:
        self.update_image(cam)

        load = Image.open(cam.getPlace() + "/image.jpeg")
        load.thumbnail((400, 300))
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        img = self.imgs.get(cam.getPlace())
        if img:
            img.image = render
        # What do you want to do if it's not one of the four expected?
        # Your existing code just ignores the image but still counts time,
        # so that's what I did here.

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error updating cam '{cam.getPlace()}: {e!r}")
    else:
        print("And " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " to run show image")

    self.root.after(0, self.show_image, cam)
```

Comment: Do you think that creating an array and adding the labels there would help? because I will be using only n number of labels.

Comment: @SantiagoPardal A list (I assume that's what you meant by "array"—you could use a `np.array` or something instead, but there's no good reason to…) would work, but a dict is even simpler.

Answer (score -1):

After quick review if you remove step two to not actual show it and just save it straight to the computer this will help cut down on the ram. Do you have any details on how much RAM you have and how much the computer is using during the process? Another could be adding a step to format the image to a certain size as it might be too large to process large quantities.

Comment: My computer has 8gb of ram, and the process acumulates ram, goes from 0 to 1.8gb and the it crashes.